# How to catch TCPDF Exception TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image

Tags: php, pdf, exception, tcpdf

I want to generate a PDF out of a Product.
But when some images are missing, I get an TCPF ERROR.

```
TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image...
```

Is there a usecase to go on without aborting?
Already tried to catch it with the classic Exception Handler, bute doesnt work:

```
try {
      $pdf->writeHTML($renderedView, true, 0, true, 0);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       return $e->getMessage();
     }
```

THANKS for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general an ERROR can not be catched. You have to transform your error to an exception so you can catch it but this isnt a best practise.

Its better you test your $renderedView for the image size before you put it to TCPDF

Answer (score 5):

You can `catch` the exception only if you `define('K_TCPDF_THROW_EXCEPTION_ERROR', true)`
There is a constant `K_TCPDF_THROW_EXCEPTION_ERROR` that determines what  TCPDF does in case of error.

`define('K_TCPDF_THROW_EXCEPTION_ERROR', true)` will throw exceptions in case of errors

`define('K_TCPDF_THROW_EXCEPTION_ERROR', false)` will echo the error and exit script execution.

Handled by method `Error` in `tcpdf:2921`

> Throw an exception or print an error message and die if the K_TCPDF_PARSER_THROW_EXCEPTION_ERROR constant is set to true.